# How to disable Android emulator animations in Travis?

Tags: android, travis-ci, android-espresso

I am running Espresso tests in the Travis CI. When I run my tests in my device, I normally disable all my animations so I don't have to use Thread.sleep all the time.

But I really don't know how to do this in the Travis CI, so my tests fail without the Thread.sleep. I looked over the internet... but I didn't find any tutorial about how to do disable the animations in the emulator

I could use idling resource in Espresso, I know. But some times I would prefer not to.

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30044012/1083957)?

Comment: Well, this is a good option. Thanks! But I was looking for a command directly in the travis.yml. Anyway, if this is the only option, that's the one I will use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you try @azizbekian's path, I wrote about this [here](https://github.com/ardock/android-topeka/issues/1), created new test rules [here](https://github.com/ardock/android-topeka/tree/65c03fa2e3ae47810de0843196cd278057ed14c8/app/src/androidTest/java/com/google/samples/apps/topeka/rule) and tested it [here](https://github.com/ardock/android-topeka/branches/all)

I confirm @Testujaca Malpeczka path works on Travis-ci for Android APIs 17-22 as discussed [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka/pull/69)

If you are looking for a solution for latest Android APIs and tools, work in progress [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42731625/1009132) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43090804/1009132)

```
before_script:
  # Wait for emulator fully-booted and disable animations
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
```

It also works in Circle-ci and probably any continuous integration build server, see [broken link here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160411180215/http://riggaroo.co.za/setting-circle-ci-test-deploy-build-android-app/)

```
test:
  pre:
    - ...
    - circle-android wait-for-boot
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
    - adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0
    - adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0
    - adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0
```

My extended test rules work for Android APIs 15-22, and there was a bug in Android 23 emulator.

I'll try it for later versions 24+ using android-topeka sample another day, probably it works.

Any help, improvement or effective alternative using `sdkmanager` would be much appreciated.

Comment: Didn't work for me - `android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click' on view 'Animations or transitions are enabled on the target device.`. Using emulator API 22.

Comment: I think that it works and your error message is generic. If you create a new question, I'll try to help you.  Probably, the lock screen is overlapping your activity (explained in the links I shared).

Comment: Nope, I have 8 test cases and I only get one failure. I can not reproduce it on my own computer, only on travis.

Comment: It seems that the problem is not related to animation - I've got the same message when performing an action on wrong target.

Comment: [Green](https://www.travis-ci.org/albodelu/jtt_android/builds/238501694) :). seems that an issue with the [screen size](https://github.com/albodelu/jtt_android/blob/440bf5332b0d970096fc392090831cff55cf005d/.travis.yml#L35) due to [landscape tests](https://github.com/albodelu/jtt_android/blob/master/JttAndroidTest/src/com/aragaer/jtt/LandscapeTest.java). I used a nexus 4 device with skin 768x128 to fix it.

Comment: Further information about screen sizes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32914660/1009132), I just added this case.

Answer (score 5):

If it possible use adb shell command:

```
adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0.0
adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0.0
adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0.0
```

tested on jenkins ci